# make search box empty when user reurns to homepage

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a front end for my website in JSP having a search box. It's working fine and retrieves results. The problem is that when user again returns to the front page where the search box is located the text box retains the text that user had searched previously. I want to make it empty. So, how should I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.onload`:

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("search field id").value = "";
}
window.onload = init;
```

**UPDATE:**

`window.onload` will not work in-case of browser back button used in Firefox, Opera and Safari.

There is a workaround for this as well. Just add the `onunload=""` to your body tag will do the trick:

```
<body onunload="">
```

Comment: :Thank you !So it is working fine when I press the back button. But if I click the back arrow button provided in my browser, it doesn't seem to work ! i.e. the text box yet retains the string.

Comment: which browser you are using? window.onload does not work in Safari, Opera and Firefox in case of browser back.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Internet Explorer. Once I press the back button and refresh the page, only then it works.